# Numerous Programs don't appear in Windows Start/Search

Tags: windows-server-2016

On Windows 2016 Data Center, I click the "Start" or "Search" button in lower left.  I type for example "BizTalk" and none of the BizTalk utilities show up.  I don't want to limit my question to BizTalk.  I have a Dev server and a QA server.  On Dev, I can type 'schedule' and it finds the windows task scheduler.  But on the QA server, I type 'schedule' and nothing found.  (I have to use a pinned task under the account I'm using that gets me to task scheduler, BizTalk Admin console, etc...)

What do I need to do to get these programs to appear?  Is something to do with an indexing tool?

Comment: Make sure Windows Search/Superfectch is enabled as a service

Comment: For SuperFetch: The OS is not presently configured to run this application. 
I enabled "Windows Search".  Does it require some indexing time first? Or a reboot?  Nothing has changed.